# Android: view is displayed before calling setContentView R.layout

Tags: android, class, debugging, adb, setcontentview

I'm studing an app and debugging it. I set breakpoint on first line of onCreate in MainActivity. However, app action bar is displayed before the next line "setContentView(R.layout." and before "super.onCreate" is stepped over. In other app action bar is for some reason not displayed even after I step over "setContentView(R.layout." (however screen becomes white with only status bar). Apps both have activity_main.xml, manifests describe both as

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

View that is displyed before setContentView is called differs that it includes custom View class, I set breakpoints in it's constructors, they are called during setContentView.

Why one app shows action bar before setContentView and in second case action bar is not shown even right after setContentView?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing that one of the activitys is extending actionBarActivity and the other is not

Comment: standard device toolbar?

Comment: With fast load actionbar extends Activity, with slow loading: AppCompatActivity. @Mahmoud.M

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is related to theme attribute which is set in `AndroidManifest.xml` for that activity ?

Activity with normal theme (with toolbar/actionbar enabled) is showing with this toolbar even before setting layout to give perception of fast loading app.

While Activity with disabled toolbar/actionbar via theme is not showing it at the beginning till layout is really inflated and added.

Comment: One that displays actionbar with delay have style with: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">. Thank you!

Comment: Can't we do anything about that? At least, changing the background color?